# Laravel - How do I write a test for this?

Tags: laravel

Still pretty new to testing and can't work this out. How do I prevent Spatie's package from actually running here. I just want to fake a response from it.

Example Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Spatie\SslCertificate\SslCertificate;

class SSLController extends Controller {

 function getIsValid(){

     $certificate = SslCertificate::createForHostName('https://example.url');

     return $certificate->isValid();

    }
}
```

Example Test:

```
<?php 

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Spatie\SslCertificate\SslCertificate;

class SSLCheckPlugInTest extends TestCase {

    public function it_returns_the_ssl_certs_status(){

         $this->mock(SslCertificate::class,function($mock){
            $mock->shouldReceive('createForHostName')->once();
        });

        $response = $this->get('/path-that-calls-the-controller-above');

    }
}
```

This example code still triggers the actual call in the package (to example.url) and returns:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method createForHostName(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_2_Spatie_SslCertificate_SslCertificate should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

*edit*

@bishop suggested writing a mock just for that one isValid method, but I can't work out how to do that.

Comment: really, you shouldn't be trying to test code that isn't yours. `SslCertificate` isn't yours, so why are trying to test it?

Comment: This is the thing, I'm not. I'm just wanting to fake a response from it not actually call it.

Comment: Mock your `getIsValid` method, instead.

Comment: @bishop sounds good. Not a clue how to do that lol

Comment: @RobertCooper - it looks like you should instead try and use HTTP testing, but if your controller method solely consists of this code, I don't see the point of even doing that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/http-tests

Comment: @DerekPollard yeah - the example above is simplified code for SO. I'm using http tests, but still cant work out how to fake the response from the controller without resorting to `if (App::environment('testing')) {` in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

The `$this->mock()` method in a Laravel's tests cases is specifically meant for mocking an instance of an object in Laravel's service container. From the docs:

> When mocking an object that is going to be injected into your
>   application via Laravel's service container, you will need to bind
>   your mocked `instance` into the container as an instance binding.

You can use Mockery directly instead to mock other classes or instances that won't be loaded into the service container.

In my opinion you should mock both the `createForHostName` and `isValid` methods. The purpose of your test would basically then be just to check that your controller method returns what it should given a known validity of a certificate.

You can first mock the `SslCertificate` instance that you want to return from `createForHostName` with something like this:

```
$certificateMock = Mockery::mock('overload:Spatie\SslCertificate\SslCertificate');
$certificateMock->shouldReceive('isValid')->once()->andReturn(True);
```

We're [overloading](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#overloading) the class above so that we can mock both instance methods and static methods of the class.

Then you can mock the `createForHostName` method to return an instance of the mocked class from above:

```
$certificateMock->shouldReceive('createForHostName')->once()->andReturn($certificateMock);
```

Answer (score 1):

It’ll be difficult to mock `SslCertificate` because you’re using it statically.

Instead, you should inject it into the class (or method). That way, it’ll be resolved by Laravel’s service container, so you’ll be able to mock it.

```php
class SSLController extends Controller
{
    function getIsValid(SslCertificate $sslCertificate)
    {
        $certificate = $sslCertificate->createForHostName('https://example.url');

        return $certificate->isValid();
    }
}
```

---

```php
class SSLCheckPlugInTest extends TestCase
{
    public function it_returns_the_ssl_certs_status()
    {
        $this->mock(SslCertificate::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('createForHostName')->once();
        });

        $response = $this->get('/path-that-calls-the-controller-above');
    }
}
```

Now, when the controller is ran, it’ll check the container for `SslCertificate` and find your mock and execute the expectations.

Comment: It's not difficult to mock static methods. It's what Mockery's [Aliasing](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#aliasing) is there for.

Also, it doesn't make sense to load an instance into the service container when the intent is to only call static methods on the class.

Comment: From that link: _Even though aliasing classes is supported, we do not recommend it._

Comment: _it doesn't make sense to load an instance into the service container when the intent is to only call static methods on the class._ The service container is for services. An “SSL certificate checker” is a service. Put it in the container, and you are able to swap it out for an alternative implementation for testing.